# Incremental build for bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

I did use the Make to build bitcoin source  [https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin].
every thing went ok.

then I have changed one of file bitcoind.cpp , and issue the Make command again, but this time Make has tried to build all bitcoin source again.

my question is how to do Incremental build for  bitcoin?

my system is ubuntu, and g++ is Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general how-to-build or how-to-make question and probably belongs on Linux or Ubuntu forums somewhere.

Comment: @Willtech,  look, this is explanation regarding "bitcoincore-development". This tag should be used for questions regarding Bitcoin Core development. This includes questions about the source code and development of Bitcoin Core

Comment: Kind of, yes ... if make is not behaving correctly, then it must be found why. As explained in “how to raise a good question”, it should show how the OP has given some efforts into debugging the error. Just throwing a problem here is deemed to be unsuccessful- we all are busy working. That said, I guess a fresh start with make/automake and a “hello world” should be first steps. If you don’t know how to do this, then willtech is right. If you were able to do so, next step would be to verify versions and maybe log file of involved tools.

Comment: If you don’t know how make/automake/autoconf work, again, willtech is right. And if then an error is in bitcoin code in line xyz, then this is the right platform :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to incrementally make. You either make or you don't.

<s>But, you could try `>make bitcoin-qt` and see if it just makes that module?</s> Nope:

```
>make bitcoin-qt
make: *** No rule to make target 'bitcoin-qt'.  Stop.
```